# Hide a certain div on a click of a label using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Why is that when I put the checkboxes inside a label, It seems to stop working

This was my html code.

```
<label> <input type="radio" name="form-showhide" checked="checked" required value="call">Call </label>
<label> <input type="radio" name="form-showhide" value="email">Email </label>
```

and this is my jQuery code.

```
$("#lcall").live('click', function() {
    $("#additional-info").show();
});
$("#lnk2").live('click', function() {
    $("#lmail").hide();
});
```

Comment: Where are the elements with id lcall and lnk2  ?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `live()` has been deprecated for many years. Also please provide a [mcve]. None of the ID's in the script exist in the html

Answer (score -1):

This Is what I do and it works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggler').click(function() {
    $('.toggle').toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="toggler">Click Me</p> <p class="toggle">I will hide</p>
```